# How do I update state but not trigger the infinite useEffect loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update state in a higher-order component from a child. My solution is to set state to true after setting tags. useEffect runs when state is true, firstly updating state in the parent component and then updating state to false, which halts its invocation. My aforementioned solution is the only way I've managed to prevent useEffect's infinite loop.

```
  const Student = ({ 
  appendTags,
  student: {
    id: studentId,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    pic,
    email,
    company,
    skill, 
    grades,
    tags: studentTags
  }}) => {
  const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  const [tag, setTag] = useState('');
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const [stateUpdated, setStateUpdated] = useState(false);
  const [displayGrades, setDisplayGrades] = useState(false);
  
  const onTagsSubmit = e => {
    if (tag.length) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      setTags(prevState => [...prevState, tag]);
      setStateUpdated(true);
      setTag('');
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stateUpdated) {
      appendTags(studentId, tags);
      setStateUpdated(false);
    };
  }, [stateUpdated, setStateUpdated, tags, appendTags, studentId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what we have, if you remove `stateUpdated`.

I presume than on `appendTags()` call the parent component changes its state and gets re-rendered. After that the `appendTags` function is recreated. The child component `Student` is recreated, too. Student's `useEffect` sees that one of the dependencies, `appendTags`, has changed, so it has to be re-executed. It calls the `appendTags()` and we have a loop.

To fix it, you need to wrap `appendTags` into `useCallback` hook inside the *parent* component:

```js
const appendTags = useCallback((id, tags) => {
  // update local state
}, []);
// ...
return <Student appendTags={appendTags} /* (...) */ />
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Whenever a student component re-renders, the student tags are missing.

Comment: @MoonShine could you post the code of both components so I can sort out the problem? Or share a link to project on a site like codesandbox?

Comment: I've solved it. Thank you.